# Correcting dates with apply function pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, timestamp

I have a DataFrame with dates in the following format:

12/31/2000 20:00    ***(month/day/year hours:minutes)***

The issue is that there are some dates that are wrong in the data set, for instance:

**10/12/2003 24:00** should be **10/13/2003 00:00**

This is what I get when I run dfUFO[wrongFormat]

[image]

So I have the following code in a pandas notebook to reformat these dates:

```
def convert2400ToTimestamp(x) :
    date = pd.to_datetime(x.datetime.split(" ")[0], format='%m/%d/%Y')
    return date + pd.Timedelta(days=1)

wrongFormat = dfUFO.datetime.str.endswith("24:00", na=False)    
dfUFO[wrongFormat] = dfUFO[wrongFormat].apply(convert2400ToTimestamp, axis=1)
```

This code results in

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

I don't really get what this error means. Something I'm missing?

**EDIT: Changed to**

```
dfUFO.loc[wrongFormat, 'datetime'] = dfUFO[wrongFormat].apply(convert2400ToTimestamp, axis=1)
```

But datetime now shows values like 1160611200000000000 for date **10/11/2006**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse your `datetime` column to "correctly named" parts and use `pd.to_datetime()`:

Source DF:

```
In [14]: df
Out[14]:
                datetime
388  10/11/2006 24:00:00
693   10/1/2001 24:00:00
111   10/1/2001 23:59:59
```

Vectorized solution:

```
In [11]: pat = r'(?P<month>\d{1,2})\/(?P<day>\d{1,2})\/(?P<year>\d{4}) (?P<hour>\d{1,2})\:(?P<minute>\d{1,2})\:(?P<second>\d{1,2})'

In [12]: df.datetime.str.extract(pat, expand=True)
Out[12]:
    month day  year hour minute second
388    10  11  2006   24     00     00
693    10   1  2001   24     00     00
111    10   1  2001   23     59     59

In [13]: pd.to_datetime(df.datetime.str.extract(pat, expand=True))
Out[13]:
388   2006-10-12 00:00:00
693   2001-10-02 00:00:00
111   2001-10-01 23:59:59
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

from [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

> Assembling a datetime from multiple columns of a DataFrame. The keys
>   can be common abbreviations like:
>
> `['year', 'month', 'day', 'minute', 'second','ms', 'us', 'ns']`
>
> or plurals of the same

Comment: Nice answer. I didn't know you could use `pd.to_datetime` on a `DF` level like that.